# separate css style for android

Tags: css, mobile, styles

I'm creating a mobile version of my website.

I have used these codes with relevant css for the screen size:

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="phone.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="pad.css" />`

now these css codes are fine for iphone, ipod touch and even ipad. Testing this on my android (samsung galaxy y) turning the page landscape blocks off most of the design due to screen width of the device. Is there a way to add another link type code but targeting android users? or even any other then the ios?

so I can change them codes to auto to fit all the devices it runs on? 
(note I know can choose auto with the 2 css listed above before anyone states that. But it will not look right hence why I want a third css page).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but if I did, this should do it:

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); //get the user agent
var android = (userAgent.indexOf("android") != -1);
if(android) { //if client is running Android
    document.head.innerHTML += "<link.../>"; //add an Android-specific stylesheet
}
else {
    document.head.innerHTML += "<link.../>"; //use the regular stylesheet otherwise
}
```

**Note:** you have to remove your `<link>`s initially, and let the JavaScript add them.

Comment: ok abody. thank you but i have added this to my page and still its reading phone.css and not other.css (which is what I want to use for anything other then ios.) basically is there not a media="android" command?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. Let me update my answer with more detail.

Comment: @KevHopwood Okay, added some notes. Please see updated answer.

Comment: yes ok. I have entered this '<script type="text/javascript">
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); //get the user agent
var android = (userAgent.indexOf("android") != -1);
if(android) { //if client is running Android
    document.head.innerHTML += "other.css"; //add an Android-specific stylesheet
}
</script>' and it does not work.

Comment: @KevHopwood You have to add the whole `link` tag in the `document.head.innerHTML +=` part. Something like: `document.head.innerHTML += "<link href = 'other.css' rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css'/>";`

Comment: still no luck with this: <script type="text/javascript">
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); //get the user agent
var android = (userAgent.indexOf("android") != -1);
if(android) { //if client is running Android
    document.head.innerHTML += "<link href = 'other.css' rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css'/>"; //add an Android-specific stylesheet
}
</script>

Comment: @KevHopwood Can you provide a live link to your site?

Comment: www.xclo.co.uk/mobile/free.html

Comment: @KevHopwood It works for me, the stylesheet gets successfully added when testing from Android.

Comment: hey. thanks for that. I'm testing it on my android and it looks like its loading phone.css and not other.css. I can tell this because my border ratio in phone.css is set to width: 450px; in landscape and in other.css its set to width: auto; which should fit the dimensions of the screen. but it does not. thats on my galaxy y.

Comment: @KevHopwood Sorry, I don't know what that could be then :( It really is loading `other.css` for me.